# How to register MousemotionListener

Tags: java, awtrobot

How to Register MouseMotionListener without using Applet,JFrame,JPanel or anything.Because i want to capture mouse positions when mouse is just moved in a System?

```
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*; 
class Mouseposition extends MouseAdapter
{
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
{
System.out.println("MOuse x : "+MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x+ "Mouse Y : "+MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y);
}
public static void main(String args[])
{
//--- register for Mouse events
----
while(true);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, Java won't listen to global OS events in this way.

You could use a JNI/JNA hook into the OS, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590226/working-example-of-jna-mouse-hook) or [example](https://code.google.com/p/jnativehook/) or use a `Thread` to constantly poll the `MouseInfo` class, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18885247/how-do-i-make-my-jwindow-window-always-stay-focused/18885346#18885346) and [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13061122/getting-rgb-value-from-under-mouse-cursor/13061320#13061320), which probably isn't very efficient...